# Tabs losing focus in IE jquery ui tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs, focus

I have a page with a  3 tab layout and each tab contains small forms. For accessibility reasons I am paying close attention to tabbing through the page. When I tab through and hit enter in FF & Chrome the focus stays on the tab. In IE 6,7,8 it jumps to the top of the page which causes a big problem for non or low vision users. This same thing occurs on the demo page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

I have tried many ways of setting focus with onclick on the element and it just doesn't work.

Any suggestions on how to fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({selected:2} );
```

The first tab is 0.